# What is the interval from C double flat to E double sharp called?

Tags: theory, intervals

What is this interval called in terms of relative scale degrees?

[image: C double flat up to E double sharp]

Comment: Just as a side-note, you might be better off writing this as a Bb and an F#, if you want people to actually play it. That's an augmented fifth.

Comment: This is a lot like asking, "How do I render an acute, a grave, a circumflex and a tilde above the same vowel?". A guru for some typesetting engine might be able to give you an answer, but it's a quite useless feat except for displaying "mad typesetting skillz". The thing you want to achieve simply doesn't occur in any reasonable text.

Comment: @KilianFoth: That actually would be useful if you're in a metal band (though you'd probably want them over a consonant, rather than a vowel).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be a quadruply augmented 3rd and would be written as AAAA3.

C to E alone is obviously a major third (M3). From there realize that by adding a double sharp to the E you increase the distance by two semitones the and the resulting interval C to E♯♯ is a doubly augmented third (AA3). From there you can see by lowing the C two semitones results in  the interval being increased by two more semitones resulting in the quadruply augmented 3rd.

Doubly augmented intervals in general are rare as seen in [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15430/are-doubly-augmented-and-doubly-diminished-intervals-practical), so I doubt you'll see it outside a theoretical context.

Answer (score 10):

When you come across something like this, you should remove all the accidentals and add them one at a time:

- C- E: major 3rd
- C- E#:augmented 3rd
- C -Ex: double augmented 3rd
- Cb- Ex: triple augmented 3rd
- Cbb-Ex: quadruple augmented 3rd.

Which I doubt you'll ever meet, even if it exists. Most likely it'll be Bb -F# which is a augmented 5th interval or Bb - Gb which is a minor sixth.

Comment: This is a great approach. Also helps with oddities such as E# to B  which was confusing me to try and count on a piano…