# What interval is from G♭ to A♯ (same octave)?

Tags: intervals

It is a number 2 interval, but being 4 semitones, it is beyond an augmented second. So, what it is?

Comment: related: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15430/are-doubly-augmented-and-doubly-diminished-intervals-practical

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The interval from any G (flat / sharp / neutral) to any A (flat / sharp / neutral) (in the same octave) is always a *second*. In your case, since the G is flat and the A is sharp, you have a *doubly augmented* second.

Of course, this interval is sonically equivalent to a major third.

Comment: is there a symbol for that? `AA2` perhaps?

Comment: @fferri: In practice it occurs very rarely, and I haven't yet seen a symbol for it.

Comment: @fferri: On [this site](https://harmonia.illiacsoftware.com/support?article=206) I've found `++2` but I don't know how common and universally accepted it is.

Comment: Has anyone ever personally seen this used? I have not. I'd be curious to see an example. I cannot think of a theoretical justification for using it, either. I'd be interested in an explanation for that as well.

Comment: @HeatherS. See the question that Tim H posted as a comment to the original post: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/15430/are-doubly-augmented-and-doubly-diminished-intervals-practical

Comment: @HeatherS. In less tonal (or maybe bi-tonal) music voice leading may provide a reasonable explanation. However, I agree it is contrived.

Comment: “Of course, this interval is sonically equivalent to a major third.” This is only true in equal temperament.

Comment: @MattL.  The guys at that site may have riffed on the standard "+" symbol for augmented interval :-) .  I'll note that Dolmetsch does not list any double-anything symbol.

Comment: @HeatherS. I found a surprising example of this kind of enharmonic relations in surprisingly early music: have a look at bar 75 and 102 of violin sonata K 481 (Mozart).